# python ftplib and TLS, issues with data connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ftplib

I need to connect to a (possibly misconfigured) FTP server which only accepts TLS connections.

I'm using FTP_TLS from ftplib. I can connect, authenticate and list files.
When I try to upload files, I get a 534 error.

I get the very same behaviour with lftp, but in lftp I can work around this issue, with this flag:

```
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
```

In python, I've tried `FTP_TLS.prot_p()` but without luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the cause of the problem: the server is an IIS server and it seems that ftplib has some issues with ISS - or maybe it's IIS that has some "special needs" that ftplib doesn't takes care of.

- https://www.kodfor.com/Automating-file-transfer-via-FTP-over-TLS-using-Python
- https://www.sami-lehtinen.net/blog/python-32-ms-ftps-ssl-tls-lockup-fix

I had to subclass the FTP_TLS class and override the storbinary method:

```
class iisFTP_TLS(ftplib.FTP_TLS):
    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS
    def storbinary(self, cmd, fp, blocksize=8192, callback=None, rest=None):
        """Store a file in binary mode.  A new port is created for you.

        Args:
        cmd: A STOR command.
        fp: A file-like object with a read(num_bytes) method.
        blocksize: The maximum data size to read from fp and send over
            the connection at once.  [default: 8192]
        callback: An optional single parameter callable that is called on
            each block of data after it is sent.  [default: None]
        rest: Passed to transfercmd().  [default: None]

        Returns:
        The response code.
        """
        self.voidcmd('TYPE I')
        with self.transfercmd(cmd, rest) as conn:
            while 1:
                buf = fp.read(blocksize)
                if not buf:
                    break
                conn.sendall(buf)
                if callback:
                    callback(buf)
            ## shutdown ssl layer
            #if _SSLSocket is not None and isinstance(conn, _SSLSocket):
            #   conn.unwrap()
        return self.voidresp()
```

Comment: How about replacing unwrap with close?